# Using Volley on Android 2.3.3 and getting SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, android, ssl, android-volley, sslhandshakeexception

Our server is using SSL certified but in Android 2.3.3 with volley I get this error (Android > 4 is ok):

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate signature.

Someone knows how to solve it?